# if statement in for loop with pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I am making a Dollar Cost Average code where I want to choose between 2 equations. I made an excel spreadsheet that I'm trying to portover to python. I've gotten pretty far except for the last step. The last step has had me searching for a solution for 3 weeks now. The errors happen when I try a for loop in a df when looping through. I would like to check a column with an if the statement. If is true then do an equation if false do another equation. I can get the for loop to work and I can the if statements to work, but not combined. See all commented out code for whats been tried. I have tried np.where instead of the if statements as well. I have tried .loc. I have tried lamda. I have tried list comp. Nothing is working please help. FYI the code referring is ['trend bal'] column. ***see end with correct code.

What the df looks like:

```
    Index   timestamp         Open         High          Low  ...      rate  account bal  invested ST_10_1.0  if trend
0       0   8/16/2021  4382.439941  4444.350098  4367.729980  ...  1.000000  $10,000.00      10000         1         0
1       1   8/23/2021  4450.290039  4513.330078  4450.290039  ...  0.015242  $10,252.42      10100         1         0
2       2   8/30/2021  4513.759766  4545.850098  4513.759766  ...  0.005779  $10,411.67      10200         1         0
3       3    9/6/2021  4535.379883  4535.379883  4457.660156  ... -0.016944  $10,335.25      10300         1         0
4       4   9/13/2021  4474.810059  4492.990234  4427.759766  ... -0.005739  $10,375.93      10400         1         0
5       5   9/20/2021  4402.950195  4465.399902  4305.910156  ...  0.005073  $10,528.57      10500         1         0
6       6   9/27/2021  4442.120117  4457.299805  4288.520020  ... -0.022094  $10,395.95      10600         1         0
7       7   10/4/2021  4348.839844  4429.970215  4278.939941  ...  0.007872  $10,577.79      10700         1         0
8       8  10/11/2021  4385.439941  4475.819824  4329.919922  ...  0.018225  $10,870.57      10800         1         0
9       9  10/18/2021  4463.720215  4559.669922  4447.470215  ...  0.016445  $11,149.33      10900         1         0
10     10  10/25/2021  4553.689941  4608.080078  4537.359863  ...  0.013307  $11,397.70      11000         1         0
11     11   11/1/2021  4610.620117  4718.500000  4595.060059  ...  0.020009  $11,725.75      11100         1         0
12     12   11/8/2021  4701.479980  4714.919922  4630.859863  ... -0.003125  $11,789.11      11200         1         0
13     13  11/15/2021  4689.299805  4717.750000  4672.779785  ...  0.003227  $11,927.15      11300         1         0
14     14  11/22/2021  4712.000000  4743.830078  4585.430176  ... -0.021997  $11,764.79      11400         1         0
15     15  11/29/2021  4628.750000  4672.950195  4495.120117  ... -0.012230  $11,720.92      11500        -1       100
16     16   12/6/2021  4548.370117  4713.569824  4540.509766  ...  0.038249  $12,269.23      11600        -1       100
17     17  12/13/2021  4710.299805  4731.990234  4600.220215  ... -0.019393  $12,131.29      11700         1         0
18     18  12/20/2021  4587.899902  4740.740234  4531.100098  ...  0.022757  $12,507.36      11800         1         0
19     19  12/27/2021  4733.990234  4808.930176  4733.990234  ...  0.008547  $12,714.25      11900         1         0
20     20    1/3/2022  4778.140137  4818.620117  4662.740234  ... -0.018705  $12,576.44      12000         1         0
21     21   1/10/2022  4655.339844  4748.830078  4582.240234  ... -0.003032  $12,638.31      12100         1         0
22     22   1/17/2022  4632.240234  4632.240234  4395.339844  ... -0.056813  $12,020.29      12200         1         0
23     23   1/24/2022  4356.319824  4453.229980  4222.620117  ...  0.007710  $12,212.97      12300        -1       100
24     24   1/31/2022  4431.790039  4595.310059  4414.020020  ...  0.015497  $12,502.23      12400        -1       100
25     25    2/7/2022  4505.750000  4590.029785  4401.410156  ... -0.018196  $12,374.75      12500         1         0
26     26   2/14/2022  4412.609863  4489.549805  4327.220215  ... -0.015790  $12,279.35      12600         1         0
27     27   2/21/2022  4332.740234  4385.339844  4114.649902  ...  0.008227  $12,480.38      12700         1         0
28     28   2/28/2022  4354.169922  4416.779785  4279.540039  ... -0.012722  $12,421.61      12800         1         0
29     29    3/7/2022  4327.009766  4327.009766  4157.870117  ... -0.028774  $12,164.19      12900        -1       100
30     30   3/14/2022  4202.750000  4465.399902  4161.720215  ...  0.061558  $13,012.99      13000        -1       100
31     31   3/21/2022  4462.399902  4546.029785  4424.299805  ...  0.017911  $13,346.07      13100         1         0
32     32   3/28/2022  4541.089844  4637.299805  4507.569824  ...  0.000616  $13,454.30      13200         1         0
33     33    4/4/2022  4547.970215  4593.450195  4450.040039  ... -0.012666  $13,383.88      13300         1         0
34     34   4/11/2022  4462.640137  4471.000000  4381.339844  ... -0.021320  $13,198.53      13400         1         0
35     35   4/18/2022  4385.629883  4512.939941  4267.620117  ... -0.027503  $12,935.53      13500        -1       100
36     36   4/25/2022  4255.339844  4308.450195  4124.279785  ... -0.032738  $12,612.05      13600        -1       100
37     37    5/2/2022  4130.609863  4307.660156  4062.510010  ... -0.002079  $12,685.83      13700        -1       100
38     38    5/9/2022  4081.270020  4081.270020  3858.870117  ... -0.024119  $12,479.86      13800        -1       100
39     39   5/16/2022  4013.020020  4090.719971  3810.320068  ... -0.030451  $12,199.84      13900        -1       100
40     40   5/23/2022  3919.419922  4158.490234  3875.129883  ...  0.065844  $13,103.12      14000        -1       100
41     41   5/30/2022  4151.089844  4177.509766  4073.850098  ... -0.011952  $13,046.51      14100         1         0
42     42    6/6/2022  4134.720215  4168.779785  3900.159912  ... -0.050548  $12,487.03      14200         1         0
43     43   6/13/2022  3838.149902  3838.149902  3636.870117  ... -0.057941  $11,863.52      14300        -1       100
44     44   6/20/2022  3715.310059  3913.649902  3715.310059  ...  0.064465  $12,728.31      14400        -1       100
45     45   6/27/2022  3920.760010  3945.860107  3738.669922  ... -0.022090  $12,547.14      14500        -1       100
46     46    7/4/2022  3792.610107  3918.500000  3742.060059  ...  0.019358  $12,890.03      14600        -1       100
47     47   7/11/2022  3880.939941  3880.939941  3721.560059  ... -0.009289  $12,870.29      14700        -1       100
48     48   7/18/2022  3883.790039  4012.439941  3818.629883  ...  0.025489  $13,298.35      14800        -1       100
49     49   7/25/2022  3965.719971  4140.149902  3910.739990  ...  0.042573  $13,964.51      14900         1         0
50     50    8/1/2022  4112.379883  4167.660156  4079.810059  ...  0.003607  $14,114.88      15000         1         0
51     51    8/8/2022  4155.930176  4280.470215  4112.089844  ...  0.032558  $14,674.44      15100         1         0
52     52   8/15/2022  4269.370117  4325.279785  4253.080078  ...  0.000839  $14,786.75      15200         1         0
53     53   8/19/2022  4266.310059  4266.310059  4218.700195  ... -0.012900  $14,696.00      15300         1         0
```

What it should look like:

```
    Index   timestamp         Open         High          Low  ...   account bal  invested  ST_10_1.0 if trend     trend bal
0       0   8/16/2021  4382.439941  4444.350098  4367.729980  ...   $10,000.00      10000          1        0   $10,000.00        
1       1   8/23/2021  4450.290039  4513.330078  4450.290039  ...   $10,252.42      10100          1        0   $10,252.42        
2       2   8/30/2021  4513.759766  4545.850098  4513.759766  ...   $10,411.67      10200          1        0   $10,411.67        
3       3    9/6/2021  4535.379883  4535.379883  4457.660156  ...   $10,335.25      10300          1        0   $10,335.25        
4       4   9/13/2021  4474.810059  4492.990234  4427.759766  ...   $10,375.93      10400          1        0   $10,375.93        
5       5   9/20/2021  4402.950195  4465.399902  4305.910156  ...   $10,528.57      10500          1        0   $10,528.57        
6       6   9/27/2021  4442.120117  4457.299805  4288.520020  ...   $10,395.95      10600          1        0   $10,395.95        
7       7   10/4/2021  4348.839844  4429.970215  4278.939941  ...   $10,577.79      10700          1        0   $10,577.79        
8       8  10/11/2021  4385.439941  4475.819824  4329.919922  ...   $10,870.57      10800          1        0   $10,870.57        
9       9  10/18/2021  4463.720215  4559.669922  4447.470215  ...   $11,149.33      10900          1        0   $11,149.33        
10     10  10/25/2021  4553.689941  4608.080078  4537.359863  ...   $11,397.70      11000          1        0   $11,397.70        
11     11   11/1/2021  4610.620117  4718.500000  4595.060059  ...   $11,725.75      11100          1        0   $11,725.75        
12     12   11/8/2021  4701.479980  4714.919922  4630.859863  ...   $11,789.11      11200          1        0   $11,789.11        
13     13  11/15/2021  4689.299805  4717.750000  4672.779785  ...   $11,927.15      11300          1        0   $11,927.15        
14     14  11/22/2021  4712.000000  4743.830078  4585.430176  ...   $11,764.79      11400          1        0   $11,764.79        
15     15  11/29/2021  4628.750000  4672.950195  4495.120117  ...   $11,720.92      11500         -1      100   $11,720.92        
16     16   12/6/2021  4548.370117  4713.569824  4540.509766  ...   $12,269.23      11600         -1      100   $11,820.92        
17     17  12/13/2021  4710.299805  4731.990234  4600.220215  ...   $12,131.29      11700          1        0   $11,920.92        
18     18  12/20/2021  4587.899902  4740.740234  4531.100098  ...   $12,507.36      11800          1        0   $12,292.19        
19     19  12/27/2021  4733.990234  4808.930176  4733.990234  ...   $12,714.25      11900          1        0   $12,497.25        
20     20    1/3/2022  4778.140137  4818.620117  4662.740234  ...   $12,576.44      12000          1        0   $12,363.49        
21     21   1/10/2022  4655.339844  4748.830078  4582.240234  ...   $12,638.31      12100          1        0   $12,426.01        
22     22   1/17/2022  4632.240234  4632.240234  4395.339844  ...   $12,020.29      12200          1        0   $11,820.05        
23     23   1/24/2022  4356.319824  4453.229980  4222.620117  ...   $12,212.97      12300         -1      100   $12,011.19        
24     24   1/31/2022  4431.790039  4595.310059  4414.020020  ...   $12,502.23      12400         -1      100   $12,111.19        
25     25    2/7/2022  4505.750000  4590.029785  4401.410156  ...   $12,374.75      12500          1        0   $12,211.19        
26     26   2/14/2022  4412.609863  4489.549805  4327.220215  ...   $12,279.35      12600          1        0   $12,118.38        
27     27   2/21/2022  4332.740234  4385.339844  4114.649902  ...   $12,480.38      12700          1        0   $12,318.08        
28     28   2/28/2022  4354.169922  4416.779785  4279.540039  ...   $12,421.61      12800          1        0   $12,261.37        
29     29    3/7/2022  4327.009766  4327.009766  4157.870117  ...   $12,164.19      12900         -1      100   $12,008.56        
30     30   3/14/2022  4202.750000  4465.399902  4161.720215  ...   $13,012.99      13000         -1      100   $12,108.56        
31     31   3/21/2022  4462.399902  4546.029785  4424.299805  ...   $13,346.07      13100          1        0   $12,208.56        
32     32   3/28/2022  4541.089844  4637.299805  4507.569824  ...   $13,454.30      13200          1        0   $12,316.09        
33     33    4/4/2022  4547.970215  4593.450195  4450.040039  ...   $13,383.88      13300          1        0   $12,260.08        
34     34   4/11/2022  4462.640137  4471.000000  4381.339844  ...   $13,198.53      13400          1        0   $12,098.70        
35     35   4/18/2022  4385.629883  4512.939941  4267.620117  ...   $12,935.53      13500         -1      100   $11,865.95        
36     36   4/25/2022  4255.339844  4308.450195  4124.279785  ...   $12,612.05      13600         -1      100   $11,965.95        
37     37    5/2/2022  4130.609863  4307.660156  4062.510010  ...   $12,685.83      13700         -1      100   $12,065.95        
38     38    5/9/2022  4081.270020  4081.270020  3858.870117  ...   $12,479.86      13800         -1      100   $12,165.95        
39     39   5/16/2022  4013.020020  4090.719971  3810.320068  ...   $12,199.84      13900         -1      100   $12,265.95        
40     40   5/23/2022  3919.419922  4158.490234  3875.129883  ...   $13,103.12      14000         -1      100   $12,365.95        
41     41   5/30/2022  4151.089844  4177.509766  4073.850098  ...   $13,046.51      14100          1        0   $12,465.95        
42     42    6/6/2022  4134.720215  4168.779785  3900.159912  ...   $12,487.03      14200          1        0   $11,935.81        
43     43   6/13/2022  3838.149902  3838.149902  3636.870117  ...   $11,863.52      14300         -1      100   $11,344.24        
44     44   6/20/2022  3715.310059  3913.649902  3715.310059  ...   $12,728.31      14400         -1      100   $11,444.24        
45     45   6/27/2022  3920.760010  3945.860107  3738.669922  ...   $12,547.14      14500         -1      100   $11,544.24        
46     46    7/4/2022  3792.610107  3918.500000  3742.060059  ...   $12,890.03      14600         -1      100   $11,644.24        
47     47   7/11/2022  3880.939941  3880.939941  3721.560059  ...   $12,870.29      14700         -1      100   $11,744.24        
48     48   7/18/2022  3883.790039  4012.439941  3818.629883  ...   $13,298.35      14800         -1      100   $11,844.24        
49     49   7/25/2022  3965.719971  4140.149902  3910.739990  ...   $13,964.51      14900          1        0   $11,944.24        
50     50    8/1/2022  4112.379883  4167.660156  4079.810059  ...   $14,114.88      15000          1        0   $12,087.33        
51     51    8/8/2022  4155.930176  4280.470215  4112.089844  ...   $14,674.44      15100          1        0   $12,580.87        
52     52   8/15/2022  4269.370117  4325.279785  4253.080078  ...   $14,786.75      15200          1        0   $12,691.42        
53     53   8/19/2022  4266.310059  4266.310059  4218.700195  ...   $14,696.00      15300          1        0   $12,627.70
```

Python Code:

```
from ctypes.wintypes import VARIANT_BOOL
from xml.dom.expatbuilder import FilterVisibilityController
import ccxt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import config
import schedule
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
#pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import time

import yfinance as yf

ticker = yf.Ticker('^GSPC')

df = ticker.history(period="1y", interval="1wk")
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns = {'Date':'timestamp'}, inplace = True)
#df.drop(columns ={'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Volume'}, inplace=True, axis=1)
df.drop(columns ={'Dividends', 'Stock Splits'}, inplace=True, axis=1)
# df['Close'].ffill(axis = 0, inplace = True)

invest = 10000
weekly = 100

fee = .15/100
fees = 1-fee 

df.loc[df.index == 0, 'rate'] = 1
df.loc[df.index > 0, 'rate'] = (df['Close'] / df['Close'].shift(1))-1

df.loc[df.index == 0, 'account bal'] = invest
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'account bal'] = (df.loc[i-1, 'account bal'] * (1 + df.loc[i, 'rate'])) + weekly

df['invested'] = (df.index*weekly)+invest
    
#Supertrend
ATR = 10
Mult = 1.0

ST = ta.supertrend(df['High'], df['Low'], df['Close'], ATR, Mult)
df[f'ST_{ATR}_{Mult}'] = ST[f'SUPERTd_{ATR}_{Mult}']

df[f'ST_{ATR}_{Mult}'] = df[f'ST_{ATR}_{Mult}'].shift(1).fillna(1)

df.loc[df[f'ST_{ATR}_{Mult}'] == 1, 'if trend'] = 0
df.loc[df[f'ST_{ATR}_{Mult}'] == -1, 'if trend'] = weekly


# df.loc[df.index == 0, 'trend bal'] = invest
# for i in range(1, len(df)):
#     np.where(df.loc[df[f'ST_{ATR}_{Mult}'] == 1, 'trend bal'], (df.loc[i-1, 'trend bal'] * (1 + df.loc[i, 'rate'])) + weekly, df.loc[i-i, 'trend bal'] + df['if trend'])



# df.loc[df.index == 0, 'trend bal'] = invest
# for i in range(1, len(df)):
#     if df[f'ST_{ATR}_{Mult}'] == 1:
#         df.loc[i, 'trend bal'] = (df.loc[i-1, 'trend bal'] * (1 + df.loc[i, 'rate'])) + weekly
#     else:
#         df.loc[i, 'trend bal'] = df.loc[i-i, 'trend bal'] + df['if trend']


# for i in range(1, len(df)):
#     df.loc[df[f'ST_{ATR}_{Mult}'].shift(1) == 1, 'trend bal'] = (df.loc[i-1, 'trend bal'] * (1 + df.loc[i, 'rate'])) + weekly
#     df.loc[df[f'ST_{ATR}_{Mult}'].shift(1) == -1, 'trend bal'] = df.loc[i-i, 'trend bal'] + df['if trend'] 


#df.to_csv('GSPC.csv',index=False,mode='a')

# plt.plot(df['timestamp'], df['account bal'])
# plt.plot(df['timestamp'], df['invested'])
# plt.plot(df['timestamp'], df['close'])
# plt.show()
print(df)
```

What some errors looks like:

```
    np.where(df.loc[df[f'ST_{ATR}_{Mult}'] == 1, 'trend bal'], (df.loc[i-1, 'trend bal'] * (1 + df.loc[i, 'rate'])) + weekly, df.loc[i-i, 'trend bal'] + df['if trend'])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in where
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (36,) () (54,)
```

Another error:

```
line 1535, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

No error but not the correct amounts:

```
df['trend bal'] = 0
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[df[f'ST_{ATR}_{Mult}'].shift(1) == 1, 'trend bal'] = (df.loc[i-1, 'trend bal'] * (1 + df.loc[i, 'rate'])) + weekly
    df.loc[df[f'ST_{ATR}_{Mult}'].shift(1) == -1, 'trend bal'] = df.loc[i-i, 'trend bal'] + df['if trend']
```

See photo of screenshot of excel formula:
[excel spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eANNQ.png)

*** Made correct calculations thanks to Ingwersen_erik:

```
from re import X
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

df = pd.read_csv('etcusd.csv')


invest = 10000
weekly = 100

fee = .15/100
fees = 1-fee 

df.loc[df.index == 0, 'rate'] = 1
df.loc[df.index > 0, 'rate'] = (df['Close'] / df['Close'].shift(1))-1

df.loc[df.index == 0, 'account bal'] = invest
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'account bal'] = (df.loc[i-1, 'account bal'] * (1 + df.loc[i, 'rate'])) + weekly

df['invested'] = (df.index*weekly)+invest

MDD = ((df['account bal']-df['account bal'].max()) / df['account bal'].max()).min()

#Supertrend
ATR = 10
Mult = 1.0

ST = ta.supertrend(df['High'], df['Low'], df['Close'], ATR, Mult)
df[f'ST_{ATR}_{Mult}'] = ST[f'SUPERTd_{ATR}_{Mult}']

df[f'ST_{ATR}_{Mult}'] = df[f'ST_{ATR}_{Mult}'].shift(1).fillna(1)

df.loc[df.index == 0, "trend bal"] = invest

for index, row in df.iloc[1:].iterrows():
    row['trend bal'] = np.where(
        df.loc[index - 1, f'ST_{ATR}_{Mult}'] == 1,
        (df.loc[index - 1, 'trend bal'] * (1 + row['rate'])) + weekly,
        df.loc[index - 1, 'trend bal'] + weekly,
    )
    df.loc[df.index == index, 'trend bal'] = row['trend bal']

print(df)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? It would be helpful to edit your question to share what your initial `df` looks like, and what you want the final df to look like.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've made the edit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```py
import time
import ccxt
import warnings
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
from ctypes.wintypes import VARIANT_BOOL
from xml.dom.expatbuilder import FilterVisibilityController


warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)

invest = 10_000
weekly = 100
fee = 0.15 / 100
fees = 1 - fee
ATR = 10
Mult = 1.0

ticker = yf.Ticker("^GSPC")
df = (
    ticker.history(period="1y", interval="1wk")
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"Date": "timestamp"})
    .drop(columns={"Dividends", "Stock Splits"}, errors="ignore")
)
df.loc[df.index == 0, "rate"] = 1
df.loc[df.index > 0, "rate"] = (df["Close"] / df["Close"].shift(1)) - 1
df.loc[df.index == 0, "account bal"] = invest

df.loc[df.index == 0, "account bal"] = invest

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, "account bal"] = (
        df.loc[i - 1, "account bal"] * (1 + df.loc[i, "rate"])
    ) + weekly


df["invested"] = (df.index * weekly) + invest

# Super-trend
ST = ta.supertrend(df["High"], df["Low"], df["Close"], ATR, Mult)
df[f"ST_{ATR}_{Mult}"] = ST[f"SUPERTd_{ATR}_{Mult}"]
df[f"ST_{ATR}_{Mult}"] = df[f"ST_{ATR}_{Mult}"].shift(1).fillna(1)
df.loc[df[f"ST_{ATR}_{Mult}"] == 1, "if trend"] = 0
df.loc[df[f"ST_{ATR}_{Mult}"] == -1, "if trend"] = weekly

df.loc[df.index == 0, "trend bal"] = invest

# === Potential correction to the np.where ==============================
for index, row in df.iloc[1:].iterrows():
    row["trend bal"] = np.where(
        row[f"ST_{ATR}_{Mult}"] == 1,
        (df.loc[index - 1, "trend bal"] * (1 + row["rate"])) + weekly,
        df.loc[index - 1, "trend bal"] + row["if trend"],
    )
    # NOTE: The original "otherwise" clause from `np.where` had the
    #       following value: `df.loc[index - index, "trend bal"] + ...`
    #       I assumed you meant `index -1`, instead of `index - index`,
    #       therefore the above code uses `index -1`. If you really meant
    #       `index - index`, please change the code accordingly.

    df.loc[df.index == index, "trend bal"] = row["trend bal"]

df
```

**Result:**

| timestamp | Open | High | Low | Close | Volume | rate | account bal | invested | ST_10_1.0 | if trend | trend bal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-16 | 4382.44 | 4444.35 | 4367.73 | 4441.67 | 5988610000 | 1 | 10000 | 10000 | 1 | 0 | 10000 |
| 2021-08-23 | 4450.29 | 4513.33 | 4450.29 | 4509.37 | 14124930000 | 0.0152421 | 10252.4 | 10100 | 1 | 0 | 10252.4 |
| 2021-08-30 | 4513.76 | 4545.85 | 4513.76 | 4535.43 | 14256180000 | 0.00577909 | 10411.7 | 10200 | 1 | 0 | 10411.7 |
| 2021-09-06 | 4535.38 | 4535.38 | 4457.66 | 4458.58 | 11793790000 | -0.0169444 | 10335.3 | 10300 | 1 | 0 | 10335.3 |
| 2021-09-13 | 4474.81 | 4492.99 | 4427.76 | 4432.99 | 17763120000 | -0.00573946 | 10375.9 | 10400 | 1 | 0 | 10375.9 |
| 2021-09-20 | 4402.95 | 4465.4 | 4305.91 | 4455.48 | 15697030000 | 0.00507327 | 10528.6 | 10500 | 1 | 0 | 10528.6 |
| 2021-09-27 | 4442.12 | 4457.3 | 4288.52 | 4357.04 | 15555390000 | -0.0220941 | 10396 | 10600 | 1 | 0 | 10396 |
| 2021-10-04 | 4348.84 | 4429.97 | 4278.94 | 4391.34 | 14795520000 | 0.00787227 | 10577.8 | 10700 | 1 | 0 | 10577.8 |
| 2021-10-11 | 4385.44 | 4475.82 | 4329.92 | 4471.37 | 13758090000 | 0.0182246 | 10870.6 | 10800 | 1 | 0 | 10870.6 |
| 2021-10-18 | 4463.72 | 4559.67 | 4447.47 | 4544.9 | 13966070000 | 0.0164446 | 11149.3 | 10900 | 1 | 0 | 11149.3 |
| 2021-10-25 | 4553.69 | 4608.08 | 4537.36 | 4605.38 | 16206040000 | 0.0133072 | 11397.7 | 11000 | 1 | 0 | 11397.7 |
| 2021-11-01 | 4610.62 | 4718.5 | 4595.06 | 4697.53 | 16397220000 | 0.0200092 | 11725.8 | 11100 | 1 | 0 | 11725.8 |
| 2021-11-08 | 4701.48 | 4714.92 | 4630.86 | 4682.85 | 15646510000 | -0.00312498 | 11789.1 | 11200 | 1 | 0 | 11789.1 |
| 2021-11-15 | 4689.3 | 4717.75 | 4672.78 | 4697.96 | 15279660000 | 0.00322664 | 11927.2 | 11300 | 1 | 0 | 11927.2 |
| 2021-11-22 | 4712 | 4743.83 | 4585.43 | 4594.62 | 11775840000 | -0.0219967 | 11764.8 | 11400 | 1 | 0 | 11764.8 |
| 2021-11-29 | 4628.75 | 4672.95 | 4495.12 | 4538.43 | 20242840000 | -0.0122295 | 11720.9 | 11500 | -1 | 100 | 11864.8 |
| 2021-12-06 | 4548.37 | 4713.57 | 4540.51 | 4712.02 | 15411530000 | 0.0382489 | 12269.2 | 11600 | -1 | 100 | 11964.8 |
| 2021-12-13 | 4710.3 | 4731.99 | 4600.22 | 4620.64 | 19184960000 | -0.0193929 | 12131.3 | 11700 | 1 | 0 | 11832.8 |
| 2021-12-20 | 4587.9 | 4740.74 | 4531.1 | 4725.79 | 10594350000 | 0.0227566 | 12507.4 | 11800 | 1 | 0 | 12202 |
| 2021-12-27 | 4733.99 | 4808.93 | 4733.99 | 4766.18 | 11687720000 | 0.00854675 | 12714.3 | 11900 | 1 | 0 | 12406.3 |
| 2022-01-03 | 4778.14 | 4818.62 | 4662.74 | 4677.03 | 16800900000 | -0.0187048 | 12576.4 | 12000 | 1 | 0 | 12274.3 |
| 2022-01-10 | 4655.34 | 4748.83 | 4582.24 | 4662.85 | 17126800000 | -0.00303177 | 12638.3 | 12100 | 1 | 0 | 12337.1 |
| 2022-01-17 | 4632.24 | 4632.24 | 4395.34 | 4397.94 | 14131200000 | -0.0568129 | 12020.3 | 12200 | 1 | 0 | 11736.1 |
| 2022-01-24 | 4356.32 | 4453.23 | 4222.62 | 4431.85 | 21218590000 | 0.00771046 | 12213 | 12300 | -1 | 100 | 11836.1 |
| 2022-01-31 | 4431.79 | 4595.31 | 4414.02 | 4500.53 | 18846100000 | 0.0154968 | 12502.2 | 12400 | -1 | 100 | 11936.1 |
| 2022-02-07 | 4505.75 | 4590.03 | 4401.41 | 4418.64 | 19119200000 | -0.0181956 | 12374.7 | 12500 | 1 | 0 | 11819 |
| 2022-02-14 | 4412.61 | 4489.55 | 4327.22 | 4348.87 | 17775970000 | -0.0157899 | 12279.4 | 12600 | 1 | 0 | 11732.3 |
| 2022-02-21 | 4332.74 | 4385.34 | 4114.65 | 4384.65 | 16834460000 | 0.00822737 | 12480.4 | 12700 | 1 | 0 | 11928.9 |
| 2022-02-28 | 4354.17 | 4416.78 | 4279.54 | 4328.87 | 22302830000 | -0.0127216 | 12421.6 | 12800 | 1 | 0 | 11877.1 |
| 2022-03-07 | 4327.01 | 4327.01 | 4157.87 | 4204.31 | 23849630000 | -0.0287743 | 12164.2 | 12900 | -1 | 100 | 11977.1 |
| 2022-03-14 | 4202.75 | 4465.4 | 4161.72 | 4463.12 | 24946690000 | 0.0615583 | 13013 | 13000 | -1 | 100 | 12077.1 |
| 2022-03-21 | 4462.4 | 4546.03 | 4424.3 | 4543.06 | 19089240000 | 0.0179112 | 13346.1 | 13100 | 1 | 0 | 12393.4 |
| 2022-03-28 | 4541.09 | 4637.3 | 4507.57 | 4545.86 | 19212230000 | 0.000616282 | 13454.3 | 13200 | 1 | 0 | 12501.1 |
| 2022-04-04 | 4547.97 | 4593.45 | 4450.04 | 4488.28 | 19383860000 | -0.0126665 | 13383.9 | 13300 | 1 | 0 | 12442.7 |
| 2022-04-11 | 4462.64 | 4471 | 4381.34 | 4392.59 | 13812410000 | -0.02132 | 13198.5 | 13400 | 1 | 0 | 12277.4 |
| 2022-04-18 | 4385.63 | 4512.94 | 4267.62 | 4271.78 | 18149540000 | -0.0275032 | 12935.5 | 13500 | -1 | 100 | 12377.4 |
| 2022-04-25 | 4255.34 | 4308.45 | 4124.28 | 4131.93 | 19610750000 | -0.032738 | 12612 | 13600 | -1 | 100 | 12477.4 |
| 2022-05-02 | 4130.61 | 4307.66 | 4062.51 | 4123.34 | 21039720000 | -0.00207901 | 12685.8 | 13700 | -1 | 100 | 12577.4 |
| 2022-05-09 | 4081.27 | 4081.27 | 3858.87 | 4023.89 | 23166570000 | -0.0241188 | 12479.9 | 13800 | -1 | 100 | 12677.4 |
| 2022-05-16 | 4013.02 | 4090.72 | 3810.32 | 3901.36 | 20590520000 | -0.0304506 | 12199.8 | 13900 | -1 | 100 | 12777.4 |
| 2022-05-23 | 3919.42 | 4158.49 | 3875.13 | 4158.24 | 19139100000 | 0.0658437 | 13103.1 | 14000 | -1 | 100 | 12877.4 |
| 2022-05-30 | 4151.09 | 4177.51 | 4073.85 | 4108.54 | 16049940000 | -0.0119522 | 13046.5 | 14100 | 1 | 0 | 12823.5 |
| 2022-06-06 | 4134.72 | 4168.78 | 3900.16 | 3900.86 | 17547150000 | -0.0505484 | 12487 | 14200 | 1 | 0 | 12275.3 |
| 2022-06-13 | 3838.15 | 3838.15 | 3636.87 | 3674.84 | 24639140000 | -0.0579411 | 11863.5 | 14300 | -1 | 100 | 12375.3 |
| 2022-06-20 | 3715.31 | 3913.65 | 3715.31 | 3911.74 | 19287840000 | 0.0644654 | 12728.3 | 14400 | -1 | 100 | 12475.3 |
| 2022-06-27 | 3920.76 | 3945.86 | 3738.67 | 3825.33 | 17735450000 | -0.0220899 | 12547.1 | 14500 | -1 | 100 | 12575.3 |
| 2022-07-04 | 3792.61 | 3918.5 | 3742.06 | 3899.38 | 14223350000 | 0.0193578 | 12890 | 14600 | -1 | 100 | 12675.3 |
| 2022-07-11 | 3880.94 | 3880.94 | 3721.56 | 3863.16 | 16313500000 | -0.00928865 | 12870.3 | 14700 | -1 | 100 | 12775.3 |
| 2022-07-18 | 3883.79 | 4012.44 | 3818.63 | 3961.63 | 16859220000 | 0.0254895 | 13298.4 | 14800 | -1 | 100 | 12875.3 |
| 2022-07-25 | 3965.72 | 4140.15 | 3910.74 | 4130.29 | 17356830000 | 0.0425734 | 13964.5 | 14900 | 1 | 0 | 13523.5 |
| 2022-08-01 | 4112.38 | 4167.66 | 4079.81 | 4145.19 | 18072230000 | 0.00360747 | 14114.9 | 15000 | 1 | 0 | 13672.3 |
| 2022-08-08 | 4155.93 | 4280.47 | 4112.09 | 4280.15 | 18117740000 | 0.0325582 | 14674.4 | 15100 | 1 | 0 | 14217.4 |
| 2022-08-15 | 4269.37 | 4325.28 | 4218.7 | 4228.48 | 16255850000 | -0.012072 | 14597.3 | 15200 | 1 | 0 | 14145.8 |
| 2022-08-19 | 4266.31 | 4266.31 | 4218.7 | 4228.48 | 2045645000 | 0 | 14697.3 | 15300 | 1 | 0 | 14245.8 |